# Calling perl replacement from within a bash script/function?

Tags: regex, perl, bash

In my `bash_profile` I have this:

```
  function ht() { perl -i -pe 's|<!-- Mirrored from (.*?) -->\n||' "$a" ;}
```

I want to run `ht` to do an inline replacement on the file fed to remove an HTML Comment with the HTTrack signature, but when I run this,

```
ht file.html
```

I get:

```
Can't open : No such file or directory.
```

I suspect this is because of the quotes around my $a which interfere with the `perl` command being fed. Perhaps it prefixes the `"` literally to the filename, or something of this nature and overall it becomes the wrong filename.

I tried removing the double quotes around my `$a` but that doesn't seem to do what I want. How can I resolve this?

Comment: where is `$a` defined? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: I thought `$a` was magical bash syntax for the command line arguments fed. I used it in another function to do the same exact thing.

Comment: I think you are referring to `$@`. Generally quoted, just as you have, `"$@"`.

Comment: Nice catch @jwd, I sleazily incorporated that find into my answer... I had decided @meder needed `$*` but didn't notice she was trying to use "$a" instead.

Comment: Why don't you check your assumptions when you get an error?

Comment: @mugen kenichi - i usually do.

Comment: Next time when you run a mirror with HTTrack, just disable this message with the `--footer` command-line argument. http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html#Browser_Options

Comment: @daxim - I wasn't the one who ran HTTrack, otherwise I would have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell perl what file you're trying to run with.  Change to this:

```
function ht() { perl -i -pe 's|<!-- Mirrored from (.*?) -->\n||' "$@";}
```

Note the `$@` instead of "$a" at the end.  As @jwd points out, that's even better than `$*` in most cases.

Comment: Note that `$@` is usually preferred to `$*`, since when quoted (as `"$@"`) it will correctly deal with filenames that contain spaces.